# The set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid m(f^{-1}(x))>0\}$ has measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The following question appeared on the Northwestern University Spring 2013 preliminary exam in analysis which is freely available online.

> Show that, if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, then the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid m(f^{-1}(x))>0\}$ has measure zero.

Let this set be denoted by $S$. I claim that $S$ is countable and hence has Lebesgue measure zero. $S=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid 10^n\leq m(f^{-1}(x))\leq10^{n+1}\}$. Suppose $S$ is uncountable. Since a countable union of countable sets is countable, at least one of the sets in the union is uncountable. In particular, for some $\delta>0$, there are uncountably many $x\in S$ with $m(f^{-1}(x))>\delta$. Further, each of the sets $f^{-1}(x)$ are disjoint.

My intuition is that since $\mathbb{R}$ can be covered by countably many disjoint line segments with length $\delta$ there is *not enough room* to accommodate uncountably many of them, no matter how they're arranged. I'm having trouble formalizing this idea.

Comment: Your intuition is correct, just express the idea more conventionally.  Lebesgue measure on the real line is indeed $\sigma$-finite so just prove what you need to prove on each interval $[n,n+1]$ ($n=0, \pm 1, \pm2, ...$) and then add up the results.

Comment: Is $m$ the Lebesgue measure? I think you should clarify this in your question.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis The question is quoted exactly as it was written in the  exam. In Folland's "Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications" the symbol $m$ is used to denote Lebesgue measure. Really, I just can't imagine they would use anything else for an exam question without specifying.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson So, how about this as a final line to the proof? Since $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}[n,n+1]$ and each of these is covered by finitely many disjoint sets of measure $\delta$, $\mathbb{R}$ can contain at most countably many such sets, in contradiction.

Comment: Sounds fine.  The basic idea is that you want to show that $S=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid m(f^{-1}(x))>0\}$ has measure zero.  For that it is enough to show that $S\cap [n,n+1]$ has measure zero for each integer $n$ since then $$ m(S) \leq \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} m(S\cap [n,n+1])=0.$$  Can even do it this way:  show that $S\cap [-n,n]$ has measure zero for each   $n=1,2,3, ...$ since then $$ m(S) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty m(S\cap [-n,n])=0.$$   This is how you argue from sets of finite measure to sets of infinite measure in the $\sigma$-finite case.